# Oracle 12 C DB installation on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: software-installation, oracle, mongodb

Someone please guide me how to install Oracle 12c DB on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and Informatica ETL Tool. Thank you very much.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51060013/435605

Answer (score 4):

Please look at the following link for installing Oracle 12 DB on Ubuntu 18.04.

https://tutorialforlinux.com/2018/05/09/how-to-install-oracle-12c-r2-database-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-64bit-easy-guide/

I personally tried it out and I was able to install the DB, but the database wouldn't start. It appears to be self-deadlocked -- the stack trace shows it is waiting on `__lll_lock_wait_private` called from `localtime`

Then I followed the instructions on the following page:

https://etc.to/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=20480023

In particular, the following commands fix the hang issue:

```
cd $ORACLE_HOME/lib/stubs
rm libc*
cd ../../bin
./relink all
```

So, these steps work:

- setup your environment as per the instructions on the webpage
- runInstaller and only install the software, i.e. don't create the database
- cleanup stubs and `relink all` as above
- run dbca to create your database

Comment: after two days, you save me another stressful day. Third step (relink all and then create database) seems to do the trick for me. Thanks man!